# Is there function like this Class.getObject(Hello.a,0)?

Tags: java

For example i have class like this,

```
class Hello {
private int a;
public void Hello(int a){
this.a = a;
}
public int geta(){
return this.a;
}
}
```

From that class, I create 5 object,

```
Hello a =  new Hello(0);
Hello b =  new Hello(1);
Hello c =  new Hello(2);
Hello d =  new Hello(3);
Hello e =  new Hello(4);
```

Is there function like below to return true or false following value of a?

```
Class.getObject(Hello.a,0) >> return true
Class.getObject(Hello.a,5) >> return false
```

-------------------------------------- EDITED -------------------------------------------

Sorry for my bad explanation, in my case i used Arraylist  arr = new Arraylist (); to populate Hello Class.
and use Random r = new Random(); to generate int for Hello Constructor.

So my Code like this,

```
Arraylist <Hello> arr = new Arraylist <Hello>();
Random r = new Random();
Hello h;

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
h = new Hello (r.nextInt(10));
arr.add(h);
}
```

For this reason i want to detect,

```
if ( Class.getObject(Hello.a,0)) {
// run some code
}
```

---

Thx for reading my problem, and sory for my bad english.

Comment: What? Just create a `Hello` object, get the value of its `a` field and compare it.

Comment: you can create a list of those objects and iterate through until you find the one with value 5. Or some similar way.

Comment: If you don't have a `Hello` instance, then what are you testing?

Comment: `void` in `void Hello(int a)` actually creates a method called `Hello` that's not a constructor.

Comment: Instead of inventing syntax or method names, how about you say what you need it to *do?*

Comment: Thx for your all reply guy,, i update my question i hope you more understand,,,

Answer (score 4):

No, Java does not keep a "registry" of all objects with their associated "id"s. Neither it can do it without placing much restriction on the structure of your classes.

However, nothing prevents you from implementing your own "registry" of objects: you could define a `Map<Integer,Hello>` that defines the correspondence between the integer IDs and their corresponding objects, make that map static in `Hello`, and add objects to it during construction. This approach is dangerous, however, because it prevents the created objects from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that in Java, but I don't see why you'd want to.

Just use:

```
public boolean check(int b){
  return b == a;
}
```

So:

```
Hello me = new Hello(5)
Hello me2 = new Hello(6);

me.check(5); // true
me.check(6); // false

me2.check(5); // false
me2.check(6); // true
```

---

Regarding your edit:

This should still work for that purpose: `if(Object.check(n))` should do the trick.

Comment: Why don't you just return `b == a`?